# Change tab background using Semantic theming

Tags: css, semantic-ui

Can someone help me out with theming? I have it all set up. How would I change the background color of tab that isn't active?

http://semantic-ui.com/modules/tab.html#/definition

Using the first example and pretending there was 2 tabs instead of one.
Pretty much the CSS equivalent of `.ui.top.attached.tabular.menu > a.item:not(.active)`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to apply a style to the class

```
.ui.item.menu, .ui.item.menu .item{ your CSS here }
```

and for the active element

```
.ui.item.menu .active.item{ your CSS here }
```

Comment: in which file though? globals/site.overrides?

Comment: it's not recommended to touch of the style files of the framework .
Kindly use a new file (custom.css or theme.css ) after loading all CSS files of the framework.

Comment: we are talking about semantic theming, which provides areas to do this. you are talking about something very different